# Algorithms on graphs represented using BDDs

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, graph-theory, survey, binary-decision-diagrams

The simplest representations for graphs use adjacency matrices/lists, meaning that each node and edge is explicitly represented. The importance of implicit representations for graphs exhibiting strong regularities has long been recognized. For instance, Galperin & Wigderson (1983), Papadimitriou & Yannakakis (*A Note on Succinct Representations of Graphs*, 1986) explored the question of graphs whose adjacency matrix is represented by a Boolean formula answering whether or not (i,j) is an edge given the binary representation of the node numbers i and j. Under some commonly satisfied constraints on reductions, P-complete problems for explicit graphs become PSPACE-complete for this representation, NP-complete problems become NEXPTIME-complete, etc.

A natural approach to such regular graphs is to represent the Boolean formula using a ROBDD; the difficulty is that classical algorithms tend to enumerate nodes one by one, which incurs exponential cost on such a representation and thus is to be avoided. There have been papers published on classical problems being solved using such a representation, e.g. Gentilini et al. (*Computing strongly connected components in a linear number of symbolic steps*), Woelfel (*Symbolic topological sorting with OBDDs*).

I'm wondering whether there is some survey of such techniques, because it's inconvenient to dredge the literature in such of the state of the art...

Answer (score 1):

You may find this link is useful. 
http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/vanhoeve/mdd/

Comment: Sometimes links die without being indexed by archive.org. Could you edit to add a brief summary of the linked information?